# Practical Survey Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I am presently working on the typography for a siddur, based primarily on the Rödelheim editions. As I am doing all of the rubrications, I would rather create a user-friendly siddur, not something which annoys daveners. As such, I would like to ask questions about usability of the general populous, e.g.: what is the best position for Ma'ariv additions for motzei Shabbat?

Would such questions be on topic here?

Comment: I think not. Those questions would be "primarily opinion based," unless you provided some criteria for determining the best answer -- halachically preferable (?), more in-line with a given *nusach*, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I think if you can ask them in a way that an objective answer is possible (most common in X community, halachic considerations, etc) that'd be fine, but opinion polls aren't a good fit here.  I hope we can help you with a subset of the questions your project will raise, anyway!

Comment: @Shokhet, the siddur is certainly in Nusach Ashkenaz. The rationale for such questions is that, while it is opinion-based, it is possible to back-up answers by bringing individual siddurim as proofs.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, thank-you. I would discuss halachic concerns with a local rabbi (eg. CYLOR). The problem, at least with my example, is that it feels like there are some things which every publisher does differently. I have my own idea, but I want A) precedent and B) something which is proven to be user-friendly (eg. no sideways instructions in the margins, cf. Vilna siddur)

Comment: Please feel free to ask for feedback or opinions in [chat], which is much more free-form than the main site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see how a question like "what is the best spot in the siddur for Motza"sh maariv" as being anything but primarily opinion based. (I think it should be right after the regular maariv, not in the back, but that's just my *opinion*. ;))

If you would ask "where do most siddurim place the Motza"sh additions for maariv", that would seem to be answerable.

And as Monica said, chat is also a good place for asking our opinions that are off topic for the main site. Here's a link to [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam), our main chatroom.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Scimonster](/a/2311) that "what is the best spot" for the additions is not a good fit for Mi Yodeya, as it's primarily opinion-based. But you are asking "about usability of the general [populace]", which can have good not-really-opinion-based answers: see [advice on how to ask a good question of this sort](//ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).